# Trying to use sharedPreferences, but the app crashes

Tags: android, datepicker, sharedpreferences

I am trying to play around with sharedPreferences in order to understand how they work. I have a date picker and want the following:
When the app opens for the first time, the date picker would show up and someone selects a date. After that the date would be stored and then a textView displays the date everytime the app is opened, without the date picker appearing again. Also, I want the date stored for future reference.

This is my code:

**Main class**

```
private TextView mDisplayDate;
DialogFragment bday = new BdayPick();
public static final String TAG = "main_date";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDisplayDate = findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    }

@SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "ApplySharedPref"})
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean previouslyStarted = prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), false);
    if (!previouslyStarted) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), Boolean.TRUE);
        edit.commit();
        bday.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    } else setDateChosen();
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void setDateChosen() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        int day = prefs.getInt(String.valueOf(selected_day), 0);
        int year = prefs.getInt(String.valueOf(selected_year), 0);
        String month = prefs.getString(String.valueOf(selected_month), "0");
        Log.d(TAG, day + " / " + month + " / " + year);
        mDisplayDate.setText("The Selected date is: " + day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
}
```

**Picker class**

```
public class BdayPick extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

   // Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
@NonNull
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog,
            this,
            year, month, day);
}

@SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    //TODO calculate and show required textl
    month = month + 1;
    String date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.selected_day), day);
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.selected_month), String.valueOf(month));
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.selected_year), year);
    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

I have no build or compile errors, but when I try to open the app it simply crashes and I don't understand why.

**Edit:
Logcat is solved with this. I have edited based oin the answers:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        month = month + 1;
        String date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        /*editor.putInt(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.selected_day), day);
        editor.putString(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.selected_month), String.valueOf(month));
        editor.putInt(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.selected_year), year);
        editor.apply();
        */

    Calendar cal;
    cal= Calendar.getInstance().set(view.getYear(), view.getMonth(), view.getDayOfMonth());
    Date d = cal.getTime();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit().putString("pref_date", new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(d));
    //editor.putString("date", new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(c.getTime()));
        editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But now I have the following error:

```
incompatible types: void cannot be converted to Calendar
```

Comment: check the logcat and see the error

Comment: You are posting a log that has nothing to do with the crash

Comment: Not sure what log I should add in this case.

Comment: Search with 'exception' in the log. Then post it here.

Comment: This?
'04-06 16:19:23.842 1693-1715/system_process E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
'

Comment: You're looking for [a stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) that will likely be all in red in your logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getPreferences(int)' on a null object reference
>   at com.example.zodiac.zodiac.BdayPick.<init>(BdayPick.java:23)
> ```

You're calling `getPreferences()` on a null here:

> ```
> SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
> ```

where `<init>` refers to that the object is being initialized, with field init in this case. `<init>` is too early for `getActivity()` to return anything other than `null` - the fragment is not attached to any activity yet.

You'll need to move the code that requires a `Context` to a later phase, `onAttach()` or later in the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Comment: What if I am not using fragments? I am getting a similar null error on a main activity, while trying to use this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: You cannot use an activity as a Context before `onCreate()`. `<init>` is too early there, too.

Answer (score 0):

In Main class change `edit.commit();` to `edit.apply();`

and also use `putBoolean(..., true)` instead of `putBoolean(..., Boolean.TRUE)`.

**EDIT:
DO NOT use string resource in SharedPrefernece. Use constant string instead.
You can try to use Date formats, like:

f.e.:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance().set(view.getYear(), view.getMonth(), view.getDayOfMonth());
Date d = c.getTime();
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getAppliactionContext()).edit().putString("pref_date", new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(d));
```

and read value using:

```
try {
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getAppliactionContext()).getString("pref_date", ""));

    //DO SOMETHING WITH THE VALUE
}
catch (ParseException e){
    Log.e("PreferenceRead ", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Still crashes.

Comment: So post your full LogCat. Not just few of lines.

Comment: Tried this, but I am getting error incompatible types: void cannot be converted to Calendar

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there:

`SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

You may use: `SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());` instead.

If you want not default SharedPreferences you can use `getActivity().getPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`, but I recommend you to use default for this.